# Is there any Ubuntu version for a PC with 248 MB RAM?

Tags: system-installation, system-requirements

I need a compatible version of Ubuntu for my computer that has only 248 MB of RAM.
Would it be possible to remove Windows XP?

Comment: I deleted my answer based on your edit telling what your RAM is -- I don't think even Lubuntu will run acceptably in that little RAM.  You may have to explore the "hyper-light" Linux distros -- I used to run antiX on a 300 MHz machine with 384 MB RAM.  Slow, but it made a Win98 machine usable again.

Comment: Why? The intended use makes a difference. I'd have thought the oldest netboot you can get; assuming you're not expecting a DE.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can see older releases here http://old-releases.ubuntu.com/releases/

There is a pretty new version 16.04.3 LTS x86 (http://old-releases.ubuntu.com/releases/16.04.3/ubuntu-16.04.1-desktop-i386.iso). For this one end of life is April 2021 (https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Releases).

If computer is very old and the OS will require to many resource, consider using Lubuntu with LXDE desktop (https://lubuntu.net/). You can even get 18.04  (http://cdimage.ubuntu.com/lubuntu/releases/18.04/release/lubuntu-18.04-desktop-i386.iso).

Comment: Excuse me @nadie , edit the question. His response was very good, but I made the mistake of not explaining the RAM I have. VERY SMALL

Comment: Lubuntu 16.04 won't run at all well with 240 MB.  The described machine may be below supported minimums when 14.04 support expires.

Comment: Thanks, all day trying to install and did not work sindarme account of the amount of RAM. Add some memory to do something. Thank you @Zeiss Ikon hace

Comment: If you really want to have Ubuntu, you could try some very old releases. For Ubuntu 4.10, I have found system requirements and they say minimum 32MB of memory. Take a look: http://old-releases.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/warty/main/installer-i386/current/doc/manual/en/ch02s05.html

Comment: The problem with running an EOL version is the same as with Windows 98 or XP -- security.  Don't do it.

Answer (score 0):

Considering it's likely an older or at least weaker system anyways, you may want to look into Lubuntu:

https://lubuntu.net/downloads/

Lubuntu still has a 32 bit download for desktop even with 18.04, not sure what you're trying to use ubuntu for, but I'm pretty sure you can put other GUIs on it that will work with 32-bit, and this should still give you a good taste of ubuntu if you're still new to Linux/Ubuntu and it doesn't really have any bloat.

Edit in response to question edit:

I am curious what exactly you would want to use ubuntu for, I mean, you could try using an old ubuntu server 32-bit build which comes with no GUI by default if you're using it for something purely technical, but I'm not entirely sure where they house old ubuntu server builds, but even that might be pushing it on such a tight RAM budget. The best option with a graphical interface is still what I suggested earlier.

Comment: Excuse me @tommy61157, edit the question. His response was very good, but I made the mistake of not explaining the RAM I have. VERY SMALL