# Launching VS-code significantly slows down my Ubuntu 20.04 system

Tags: 20.04, microsoft, visual-studio-code

I have read a similar question [Why does Visual Studio Code work slow in Ubuntu?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1051621/why-does-visual-studio-code-work-slow-in-ubuntu) 
But the answer doesn't seem to work for me. Can any of you please suggest me what needs to be done, so that my ubuntu doesn't slow down inspite of running VS-code. :)
I'm using a Dell Laptop - 4GB RAM, i3 processor.(Dell Inspiron 3521 to be precise).

I'm attaching the output of top command below.

```
$ top
top - 11:40:01 up 2 days,  4:54,  1 user,  load average: 0.74, 2.57, 3.11
Tasks: 289 total,   1 running, 286 sleeping,   0 stopped,   2 zombie
%Cpu(s):  4.1 us,  1.4 sy,  0.9 ni, 88.6 id,  4.9 wa,  0.0 hi,  0.0 si,  0.0 st
MiB Mem :   3813.9 total,    292.6 free,   2427.7 used,   1093.6 buff/cache
MiB Swap:   7813.0 total,   5850.0 free,   1963.0 used.    912.1 avail Mem 

    PID USER      PR  NI    VIRT    RES    SHR S  %CPU  %MEM     TIME+ COMMAND                                                         
 446969 rohith    20   0  446336  32668   8112 S   8.2   0.8   0:21.80 tracker-store                                                   
   2298 rohith    20   0 5016380 213684  36852 S   4.3   5.5 120:22.66 gnome-shell                                                     
   1997 rohith    39  19  667620   7444   4296 S   2.3   0.2   0:08.63 tracker-miner-f                                                 
   2054 rohith    20   0  864876  45324  31072 S   2.3   1.2  50:44.60 Xorg                                                            
 446986 rohith    39  19 1291160  23100   9748 S   2.0   0.6   0:05.92 tracker-extract                                                 
 445927 rohith    20   0  824608  34444  21232 S   1.6   0.9   0:03.62 gnome-terminal-                                                 
 320208 rohith    20   0 2739580 151856  62984 S   1.3   3.9  12:11.59 Web Content                                                     
 448016 rohith    20   0  740764 165376  51232 S   1.3   4.2   0:07.91 code                                                            
 320048 rohith    20   0 4106348 264832  80484 S   1.0   6.8  45:49.49 MainThread                                                      
 354123 rohith    20   0 1006532  24320   8568 S   0.7   0.6   0:09.46 nautilus                                                        
 388853 rohith    20   0  670312  52628  23124 S   0.7   1.3   2:30.48 Discord                                                         
 389021 rohith    20   0 1245072 172520  44592 S   0.7   4.4   6:30.20 Discord                                                         
 428795 rohith    20   0 2415592 186724  12468 S   0.7   4.8   0:54.48 teams                                                           
    266 root       0 -20       0      0      0 I   0.3   0.0   0:09.90 kworker/3:1H-events_highpri                                     
   1995 rohith     9 -11 3916496   6452   3956 S   0.3   0.2  81:12.56 pulseaudio                                                      
 322643 rohith    20   0 2592608  29348  14496 S   0.3   0.8   3:01.68 Web Content                                                     
 391282 root      20   0       0      0      0 I   0.3   0.0   0:02.81 kworker/3:4-events                                              
 430472 rohith    20   0 2897892  99900  48540 S   0.3   2.6   2:48.18 Web Content                                                     
 433377 rohith    20   0 2480952  76236  25408 S   0.3   2.0   0:39.86 Web Content                                                     
 439747 root      20   0       0      0      0 I   0.3   0.0   0:01.11 kworker/u16:4-events_power_efficient                            
 446953 rohith    20   0   20616   3676   2904 R   0.3   0.1   0:02.35 top                                                             
 447335 root      20   0       0      0      0 I   0.3   0.0   0:00.06 kworker/1:4-events                                              
 448138 root      20   0       0      0      0 I   0.3   0.0   0:00.27 kworker/0:3-events                                              
      1 root      20   0  169400   6912   4124 S   0.0   0.2   1:15.90 systemd
```

Also, free command output is provided below:

```
$ free
              total        used        free      shared  buff/cache   available
Mem:        3905460     2483388      315088      289392     1106984      926000
Swap:       8000508     2010884     5989624
```